# How do I get my Samsung Note 3 to be recognized by my PC?

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, samsung-galaxy-note-3

When I plug my phone into my PC (which is running Windows 7 OS) only charging takes place. When I view my phone in Device Manager, it says that Samsung Android files are not installed. But I installed those and also tried with Samsung Kies 3 but it's still not getting connected.

Answer (score 1):

First, what you want to do ? Transfer files to the phone or make something with ADB and stuff.

Good that you have Kies 3 installed.
If transfer files. Check this: when you connect the phone there is a popup on the upper bar, sometimes you need to click it and change it to 'transfer files' - then the phone will go into MTP mode which allows you to view it in "My computer"

If make something with ADB: first try to install maybe Naked Drivers (it worked for me note 1 on win7):
http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/development/adb-fb-apx-driver-universal-naked-t2513339
, then enable debug in settings. When debug is enabled when u connect the phone it should ask for driver.
Also in bootloader and fastboot there is another driver needed but it sgould be in Naked or Kies drivers, also Android SDK have drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Trying turning phone off, take battery out. Wait 15 seconds.  Reinsert battery, turn on.  Then try connecting to PC again.  Hopefully it'll recognise the device when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the drivers for your phone. Go to the [Samsung support site](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads), which should let you download a driver for your PC that will recognize your phone.

If that does not work, scroll down your menu bar on your phone then click USB (phone should recognize it, if plugged in) then click media transfer. You can choose USB 3.0 I believe.

Comment: related: [Google OEM USB Drivers List](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)

Answer (score 0):

My Windows10 Toshiba Kira notebook had ignored my USB connected Samsung Note3 for a long time. After many attempts I solved this as follows.

I noticed my phone was recognised in "Printers and Devices" but had an error because of a metered (wireless) connection (because I needed to control usage when hotspotting), and one of the properties suggested it was looking for Bluetooth. I may have deleted this device (as I recall I didnt), but I removed and inserted the USB cable a couple of times before/during/after this whole process.

I also enabled Developer mode several times with USB debugging finally toggled OFF, then turned OFF the wireless hotsopt on the Note3. At this point, after reconnecting the USB cable I got half of an audio connection acknowledgement.

I disconnected/reconnected again and finally finally finally got the full audio connection sound!!!

I then coerced the network connection in Windows Explorer by typing in the already configured \PhoneNetworkName into the location. I made the network private and discoverable when I got the pop-up, then it all worked.

The Phone also appeared in Device Manager under Portable Devices and I had a notification "Connected as a media device" on the phone. Pressing this took me to the "USB PC connection" App offering to connect as Media device(MTP) and/or Camera(PTP) - of course MTP was already checked. This App is not found by a search in phone "Settings". I think if you could find out how to bring this App up manually it would probably solve the issue, because this setting (MTP) is all I ever had to do before with my Galaxy S2, and Ericsson M750.

Had all of the symptoms described by others, nothing else worked.

Turned on hotspotting and the connection still works, but turning it off while USB connected might have triggered something????

So, good luck. I hope this helps.